# BleakClient suggests "async with", but how can I get a handle that lasts beyond my code block?

Tags: python, async-await, with-statement, python-bleak

I wrote a Python script using the [bleak Bluetooth Low Energy client](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that works from a command line. I want to split the script into REST endpoints.

To that end, I want to replace `async with BleakClient(d, timeout=10) as client:` with something that allows me to make `client` global so that I can use it in another REST endpoint. In other words, I want `client` to hang around beyond the call that connects to the device. Any ideas?

I tried `client = await BleakClient(d, timeout=10)` but this line throws an exception: `object BleakClient can't be used in 'await' expression`.

*EDIT*

I am including the entire (truncated) Python script. Call to  ConnectAndReadChar() works. Call to ConnectUUT() does not work. Exception on line 'client = await BleakClient(d, timeout=10)', <class 'TypeError'>.

```py
import asyncio
import traceback
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient
import sys
import time

global client
        
async def ConnectAndReadChar(MAC_ID):
    d = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(MAC_ID, timeout=20)            
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while True:
        try:
            if d.address == MAC_ID:
                async with BleakClient(d, timeout=10) as client:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    res = await client.pair(protection_level=None)
                    print(res)

                    x = client.is_connected
                    print("Connected: {0}".format(x))

                    svc = client.services.get_service("Service ID")

                    thisCharacteristic = svc.get_characteristic("Char ID")
                    value = bytes(await client.read_gatt_char(thisCharacteristic))
                    print("\tValue: {0} ".format(value))

                    await client.disconnect()
                    await client.unpair()
            return
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print(e)


async def ConnectUUT(MAC_ID):
    global client
    d = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(MAC_ID, timeout=20)            
    while True:
        try:
            if d.address == MAC_ID:
                # async with BleakClient(d, timeout=10) as client:
                client = await BleakClient(d, timeout=10)
                if client is not None:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    res = await client.pair(protection_level=None)
                    print(res)

                    x = client.is_connected
                    print("Connected: {0}".format(x))
            return
        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()[0]
            print(e)

async def ReadFrames():
    global client

    try:
        svc = client.services.get_service("Service ID")
        thisCharacteristic = svc.get_characteristic("Char ID")
        return
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print(e)

async def DisconnectUUT():
    global client

    try:
        await client.disconnect()
        await client.unpair()
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print(e)
    return

async def main():
    await ConnectAndReadChar("MAC ID goes here")

    await ConnectUUT("MAC ID goes here")
    await ReadFrames()
    await DisconnectUUT()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: In most cases, anything you can use with `with` can generally also be used without it, just requiring you to do your own cleanup -- it's unusual to put critical, core functionality in a context handler, async or otherwise, without providing another path to it. I'm curioun what this BleakClient is doing such that it appears to have a hard requirement on `async with`.

Comment: When I asked a question regarding Python bleak a couple of months ago someone responded that I need to learn BLE (I assume before asking questions). Now this question is closed? How do I get help on the Internet?!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How do I get this question into a condition where someone can answer it?

Comment: That said, where you're currently asserting "throws an exception", could you _show_ that actual exception?

Comment: How do I show the actual exception?

Comment: adding: 'except Exception as e: print(e)' produces 'object BleakClient can't be used in 'await' expression'.

Comment: I'd argue that the usual practice is to not even _try_ to catch exceptions you don't have a plan to handle, and instead let the interpreter exit and throw a full stack trace; but yes, that's enough to be helpful.

Comment: `client = BleakClient(d, timeout=10); await client.connect()`

Comment: Yes, that. How do I mark that as the answer to my question?

Comment: Right now it's just a comment -- the question would need to be reopened (awaiting two more votes) before I could add it as an answer proper so it could be accepted.

Comment: While I don't think this lags debugging details (it's not a debugging question...) as it stands this isn't answerable. This kind of change depends strongly on *your REST program architecture*, e.g. whether it provides means to run background tasks etc. With the given script, the place would be inside `main` but what you are showing *isn't a REST architecture* so such an answer would fail your stated goal. Consider to [edit] the question to decide on one architecture. [from reopen review]

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your input. You are correct. The code I presented is not a REST architecture. I was having trouble knowing how to assign a value to `client` so that it could be used in multiple REST endpoints. All of the examples that I had encountered used  `async with BleakClient(d, timeout=10) as client:`. @Charles Duffy answered my question: `client = BleakClient(d, timeout=10); await client.connect()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a BleakClient as an async context manager, it implicitly performs a `connect`. You can also do this explicitly:

```
client = BleakClient(d, timeout=10)
await client.connect()
```

Comment: This answer is missing `disconnect` call which is, apparently, important for resources cleanup. https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html#bleak.BleakClient.disconnect

Comment: @STerliakov, ... important _if_ the program isn't going to be using the connection until it's completely finished execution and ready to exit, that is.

Comment: Yep, `.disconnect` should be called somewhere at the end of the program. I'd say that maintaining proper resource lifecycle from acquisition to release is still important - perhaps this `.connect` shouldn't be used as a pattern at all, passing client opened with a context manager as an argument to all these functions instead. Or these functions should belong to a class that supports context manager protocol itself, resulting in `with MyListener(...) as listener: listener.connect_and_read_char(); ...`

Comment: @STerliakov, there's no point to calling disconnect _when the program is about to exit_ -- everything gets cleaned up implicitly when the exit takes place (absent a bug in the system's bluetooth service, but those bugs tend to get noticed and cleaned up -- a system daemon with a resource leak is an obvious issue and attracts reports); it's only helpful when it's possible to release resources _before_ exit time.

Comment: @STerliakov, ...and that's the entire point of this question: the OP has a case where they want to continue using a connection _beyond_ a limited-scope block of code, for the entire rest of their program's runtime. They _already know_ how to use `async with` for a limited code block; the question was asked because they wanted to know how to continue to use a single connection indefinitely, into other functions independently invoked.

Comment: While I mostly agree that you can rely on such behavior in this specific case, it's not a thing I can suggest to anyone. Deferring cleanup to the system daemon is not a good practice, you may hit some unexpected consequences now or later. I'll post an answer today showing how such client can be maintained in rest-like architecture with several independent handlers with proper resource release.